# elementary algebra - "completing the exponential"

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics, functions

Need help with some simple algebra in the context of an unrelated statistical argument. This reminds me of "completing the square," but the functions are not quadratic.

I have an expression $\displaystyle\exp{\frac{-10}{2(x+y+1/3)}}$ (where $x,y\in (0,1)$) which I'd like to express as $\displaystyle\exp{\frac{-10}{2(x+1/3)}}+z$. Can $z$ be written as a function of $y$ only (and not dependent on $x$)?

Comment: you can write $exp(a+b)=exp(a).c $ but not $exp(a+b)=exp(a)+c$ where c is independent of a.

Comment: Is $+z$ to be taken in the exponential as well ?

Comment: @Paul The multiplicative version might help too. Does $\exp{\frac{1}{a+b}}=\exp{f(a)}*\exp{g(b)}$? What are $f$ and $g$?

Or really just $h(f(a),g(b))$ would be nice. I guess it's impossible?

Comment: Afraid so. If b is small compared to a you might approximate $\frac{1}{a+b}$ as the first few terms of a power series in $\frac{b}{a}$, then exponentiate that sum, but you will still not separate out a and b.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean

$$\exp\left(\frac{-10}{2(x+y+1/3)}\right)=\exp\left(\frac{-10}{2(x+1/3)}\right)+z(y),$$

the answer is negative because by taking the partial derivative on $y$,

$$\frac{10}{2(x+y+1/3)^2}\exp\left(\frac{-10}{2(x+y+1/3)}\right)=\frac{10}{2(x+1/3)^2}\exp\left(\frac{-10}{2(x+1/3)}\right)$$ does not hold.